# how to pass checked radio button part to action from jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

```
<table style="width: 100%; margin-left: 5px;" align="center">
<tr>
    <td style="width: 250px; ">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" onclick="chkOut();" /> Create Child Component </td>
    <td>
 <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio12" onclick="checkOut();"/> Add Component  From Another Asset
 </td>
    </tr>
</table>

var formObj=document.forms[0];
    formObj.action="ArcheTypeDevice.in?&status=AddComponent&SelectedText="+txt;
    formObj.submit();
```

Comment: if you are submitting form why you need to send it in URL ?

Comment: i dnt see, that you are passing radio button value in url atleast

Comment: i dont know how to send the checked button part to the action.plz suggest

Comment: `getDocumentById("radio1").checked` but seems poor hack. better post it in form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onCallForInterview()
{
var selectedIds;
var count=0;
for (i=0; i<document.frm.check1.length; i++)
{
if (document.frm.check1[i].checked==true)
{
if(count==0){
selectedIds=document.frm.check1[i].value; 
count=count+1; 
}
else
selectedIds=selectedIds+","+document.frm.check1[i].value;
}
}
alert(selectedIds);  
document.frm.action="<%=contextPath%>/SearchCandInfo?    action=selectcanforinterview&ids="+selectedIds;
document.frm.submit();
}
```

You can use this function if you are able to assign unique value to each radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the input element a **value**:

```
<form action="someServletUrl" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="action" value="create" />Create child
    <input type="radio" name="action" value="add" />Add component
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In the servlet, just get the selected value the usual way:

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");

if ("create".equals(action)) {
    // "Create child" is selected.
} else if ("add".equals(action)) {
    // "Add component" is selected.
}

// ...
```

No need for nasty JavaScript hacks which ain't going to work on browsers with JavaScript disabled.